# How to delete doted files with certain extention?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

Suppose we have the following 5 files:
.file1.tmp
.file2.tmp
.file3.tmp
.otherfile
anotherfile

How to delete with one bash command the files: .file1.tmp, .file2.tmp, file3.tmp?

Comment: The glob pattern would be `.*.tmp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dot before asterisk:

```
rm .*.tmp
```

It will work here, or it can be more specific:

```
rm .file{1..3}.tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
rm .file{0..3}.tmp
```

you can test it with;

```
ls .file{0..3}.tmp
```

Comment: Ichtaca had already suggested `rm .file{1..3}.tmp` five minutes before you posted and you essentially repeating it and adding the `ls` command IMO does not raise it to a level that's acceptable as a separate answer!